# Cordova 6.3.1 plugin.xml set minSdkVersion doesn't work

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm working on a plugin for cordova and would like to set the minimum sdk version. However it isn't overwritten when I try to use these options in the plugin.xml file:

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" />
</platform>
```

or in the manifest tag

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
</config-file>
```

These ways are both phonegap ways to set the sdk versions and, if I'm correct, still cordova ways. But the first one gives an error:

```
Failed to install 'plugin.demo':Error: Variable(s) missing: ANDROID-MINSDKVERSION, ANDROID-TARGETSDKVERSION
```

And the second option just add a new row with uses-sdk, which also creates a lot of errors.

How do I set the sdk version in cordova (v6+)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15" />
</config-file>
```

Comment: This works perfect, thanks! For other users, don't forget to use "cordova prepare android" before the changes are made

Comment: I'm still getting this error.  Any ideas @Quispie?  I don't quite understand where it is coming from.  Could ANY plugin that requires sdk 15+ cause this problem if another plugin or Android module requires sdk 16+?

Comment: @AlexanderPritchard If you used "cordova prepare android" and this error still exist and you copied the answer corectly, then yes, some sdk's will need a higher minSdkVersion

Comment: @AlexanderPritchard if multiple plugins require different minSdkVersions, Cordova will deliberately fail the build and make you state enforce minSdkVersion in app's main config.xml: 
    `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />`

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11023